# I was transferred 500 euros

Tags: passive-voice

Can "transfer" be used in this passive structure(not all verbs can be)?
▪︎ I was transferred 500 euros(means that 500 euros was transferred to me).

Comment: No, We use: 500 euros were transferred to me or more idiomatically, 500 euros were deposited in my account.

Answer (score 0):

It would sound rather odd. "500 euros were transferred to me" sounds better (was gets changed to were because 500 euros are plural).